# Transparent background progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to find an animated progress bar with a transparent background. I would prefer to achieve it using JQuery, Javascript and/or CSS. Is this possible? I'd like something much like this: http://www.fcm.travel/progress_bar.gif Has anyone come across such a thing?

The other questions I've seen on here show static bars, nothing animated much like the example.

Comment: why don't you just use plain CSS to make your progress bar transparent, there plenty of resources of how to do it

Comment: Edited my question to make what I want more apparent. Sorry

Comment: Forget these people good question, +1 Buddy.

Comment: if you search for ajax progress bars you will find web sites that have graphics similiar to the one you showed. Most if not all will have the ability to make the bg transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You can make anything transparent with CSS. The following makes 75% opacity (25% transparent)

```
style="opacity: .75; filter: alpha(opacity=75)"
```

(The extra filter rule is for IE)

Edit: If you care that it works as often as possible on older browsers, you would add the old `-webkit-` and `-moz-` rules

```
style="opacity: .75; filter: alpha(opacity=75); -moz-opacity: .75; -webkit-opacity: .75"
```

In the event the browser does not support opacity settings, it would automatically default back to 100% opacity which is not transparent or translucent at all

Comment: There is one for mozilla I'm sure its -moz-opacity() +1 for perfect anwser.

Comment: I edited in the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` rules. Firefox and Chrome do not need the prefix and have not needed it for quite some time. I have not tested Safari or older versions. @Steven

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by transparent, but jquery ui has a progress bar: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#animated

Answer (score 0):

Technically, Animated PNG would be neat for this. However the support for it isn't really that wide last time I checked.

So what you could do, seeing you are open for JavaScript solutions, is create a spritemap image based on 24 bit PNG's so it has nice transparancy, that contains every state for the animation. Then with JavaScript and a decent enough timer/interval, simply change the background position for the image so it looks like it's showing a live animation.

Comment: For example, the StackOverflow logo is a cropping of a larger collection of images which you can view here: http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3

Answer (score 0):

I've just made something that would interest You few days ago, take a look at this [progress bar](http://codecanyon.net/item/progress-bar/full_screen_preview/168054)